# How to make the list of listings to work properly in tex4ebook?

Tags: listings, matlab, tex4ebook

How to make the list of listings to work properly in tex4ebook?

Commands `\tableofcontents` and `\listoffigures`work correctly.

The pdf result

[image: pdf]

The epub result

[image]

I didn't found any suggestion to `lstlistoflistings` in `tex4ebook` in the internet.

A MWE follows

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mcode}

\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Algorithm}
\renewcommand{\lstlistlistingname}{List of Algorithms}

\begin{document}
\lstlistoflistings

\lstinputlisting[label = {alg:alg_01}, caption = {alg 01}]
{alg_01.m}

\lstinputlisting[label = {alg:fc_alg_02}, caption = {fc alg 02}]
{fc_alg_02.m} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: @michal.h21, I'm sorry calling you here and asking again for help, but I didn't find any hint to solve this problem. And as I also don't understand the syntax to create a config file as I've seen to solve other issues, I only have the option to ask someone I know might solve it.

Comment: I've posted an answer. I am slowly trying to work on all `tex4ht` bug reports, there were too many of them in the past few months, so I was bit exhausted :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following configuration:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\makeatletter
\ConfigureToc{lol} {}{\empty}{}{\newline}
\lst@UserCommand\lstlistoflistings{\bgroup
  \ifdefined\chapter\chapter*{\lstlistlistingname}\else\section*{\lstlistlistingname}\fi
\TableOfContents[lol]
\egroup}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

The commands that use the TOC mechanism needs a configuration. The `\TableOfContents[list of types]`. The `\lstlistoflistings` writes entries to the `filename.lol` file, so `\TableOfContents[lol]` will print these entries. It is also necessary to configure TOC type, using `\ConfigureToc{lol}`. I've used the configuration that `tex4ht` uses for all other types. It just prints the entries on separate lines.

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: It worked perfectly! I don't have words to express my gratitude. I only hope some day tex4ebook will be able to fully convert all LaTeX features to epub. The issue with equation/split/align I made a workaround. I can finally publish a epub version of my book. Once again thanks.

Comment: @FHZ I hope to look at the split issue soon. the ideal would be if Epub readers supported MathML, as images are not ideal solution anyway. but the support is non-existent, so we will always get not good results